# SELECT CASE something missing

Tags: php, sql, select

hello I need to do something like this

check a column for a vaule, if the vaule is one then $display_output is "something"
if vaule is two then $display_output is "other"

so far i have this

```
$sql_istorrenthere = $this->query("SELECT CASE WHEN torrent_download ='1' THEN $display_output = GMSG_NOTORRENT ELSE $display_output = GMSG_TORRENT ; FROM" . DB_PREFIX . "auctions"
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't set variables like that. You can set the value of torrent_download to 'something' or 'other' though:

```
$sql_istorrenthere = $this->query(
    "SELECT 
      CASE WHEN torrent_download = '1' 
        THEN 'something' 
        ELSE 'other' 
      END AS torrent_download
    FROM" . DB_PREFIX . "auctions"
);
```

Comment: how would i set $display_output then?

Comment: @FrankLy Well, not from SQL. You'll have to do that in PHP.

Comment: what i need to do is check if torrent download is one value or another, then have $display_output be something or other, changing torrent_download will no effect

Comment: @FrankLy You **can't** influence a variable from *inside* a SQL query. SQL queries are executing by databases, they don't and can't know your variables even exist. Execute the query, analyse the response and set the variable accordingly.

Comment: how do i analyse the response then is the question i guess? after i query for torrent_download what would i need to do with $display_output

Comment: @FrankLy What's in the `$sql_istorrenthere` variable? Have you tried var_dump()'ing it?

Comment: $sql_istorrenthere is just the name of the varible i am using to call the query, there is nothing in the variable

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT IF(STRCMP(torrent_download,'1'),'GMSG_TORRENT','GMSG_NOTORRENT') 
AS display_output
FROM " . DB_PREFIX . "auctions";
```

Then in PHP, you can do:

```
$response = $sql_istorrenthere -> fetch_assoc();
$display_output = $response['display_output'];
```

But there are better ways to do this, none of which involve trying to set your variable names into the query itself.

Comment: how to set $display_output if using this?

Comment: I wouldn't in the query, but assuming you want `Something` and `Other`, I'll update.

Comment: sorry must be confusing, I want $display_output to be GMSG_NOTORRENT or GMSG_TORRENT

Comment: i am getting an error with  Call to a member function fetch_assoc() on a non-object atm, still testing